# Currently try to get rails support for sql server 2005.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am currently looking to make a rails application that will be pulling requests for sql server 2005. Now I hard install the needed drivers using the following commands

```
   gem install activerecord  -v 3.2.0
   gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter -v 3.2.0
```

Now I set up the Yml file as follows.

```
development:
  <<: *default
  host: 192.168.1.160
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: iERP85_Dev
  database: iERP85_Dev
  username: name
  password: pass
```

Now I run the server to uncover this message

Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

I then go into the Gem file and add this line

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 3.2.0'

bundle install

  In Gemfile:
   activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 3.2.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
     activerecord (~> 3.2.0) x86-mingw32

   rails (= 4.1.8) x86-mingw32 depends on
     activerecord (4.1.8)
```

I then tried Update but no luck. How do I know I am using active record 3.2.0 from the gem install above? I cannot upgrade the server to 2012.

Comment: Why are you trying to use version 3.2 of the adapter gem?

Comment: I believe the 4.2 adapter only supports sql server 2012, the sugesstion comes directly from https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Comment: The 4.1 branch claims to support 2005 and higher

Comment: Really how can I enable such a version. The bundler continues to tell me the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be using rails 4.1 you need to use version 4.1.x of the adapter. Luckily this claims to support SQL server 2005.

Update your gemfile to say

```
 gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.1.0'
```

And things should work (in fact you could probably drop the version constraint altogether since only 4.1.x of the adapter will work with rails 4.1)